# Extending a TypeScript declaration that is monkey patched?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have some classes that I am using with declaration files. They work great. Actually I have a module monkeypatched with a function and some prototypes off that function.

Obviously I don't want to modify the definitions direct but I would like to extend them.

It appears that I can't do a declare module again. Any idea how I can do this?